# mysql to mongodb migration

Tags: mysql, mongodb, migration

I have table, with around 125 million records in `MySql`. I want to move it to `mongodb`.

**What would be the best approach to migrate this huge table to mongodb?**

I was thinking to fetch one by one row using a nodejs application and create an array for bulk insert in mongodb. But I think it will take too much memory *(Haven't check it though)*.

Answer (score 0):

Export that table to JSON format (f.ex. [MySQL Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import.html)) and use [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) to import it.